# Ubuntu 20.04: sudo apt-get update not Working

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install docker to my machine , but firstly just check for any updates `sudo apt-get update` and it is giving me error:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease           
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try updating `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `https` instead of `http`. (Oddly, though, when I check at my end using the `ubuntu:focal` container it updates fine using `http`.)

Comment: i have tried , anyway there is such problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with your internet, Because as you saw it's sent you connection failed error.

Check your device internet connection.

If it's has, check your router and get requested IPs Ping (as I saw it's sent request to **185.125.190.36**, **91.189.91.38** & ****91.189.91.39****).

Comment: i checked all the ips , and i have received packets with them

Comment: Change your virtual box settings to *Bridge Adapter* and Mode should be all *Allow All*. Then restart the machine.